Help to write a script for adb connect
To cast my Android phone to my desktop I enter these terminal commands:
adb tcpip 5037  
adb connect 192.168.0.xxx:5037  
scrcpy

The issue is the xxx changes daily, which causes me to find the xxx and enter all commands manually. I would like a script to automate this task. I am familiar with do loops, but not the bash language. Also I do not know what is the return code when the connect fails.
Basically, I need a do loop to cycle through the xxx, starting with 100, increment=1.
I would write the algorithm in plain English as:
execute adb tcpip 5037  
let xxx=100  
until successful connection, do...  
execute adb connect 192.168.0.xxx:5037  
if no connect, then xxx=xxx+1  
else enddo  
execute scrcpy

Could someone please help me code this for bash?

This sounds like an XY problem.  Traversing even a subset of an IP address space is rarely the right answer.  Why does the IP address change? Please [edit] your Question to improve it. Do not use Add Comment.

I do not know why the IP address of the android phone changes randomly.

@robgrune configure your DHCP server to hand out a static address?

Set your router to give the phone a fixed IP.

Best Option
I assume this is a home Wi-Fi setup. What kind of router you have? Google how to reserve an IP address for a specific device (that would be your phone) in your router. In your router you will find the MAC address of your phone and the current IP address associated with that MAC address. Reserve the current IP address for that MAC address in your router. Save the settings.
I accessed by router's setup page by going to 192.168.0.1 on a web browser like Firefox. In my router when I select Network > DHCP server on the left panel, I get the section Address Reservation in the main window. There I can reserve a specific IP address for a device. See below:

Your router setting may look different.
What you asked for
adb connect always returns 0
It looks like adb connect returns exit code 0 irrespective of whether the connection is established or not. If I type adb nonsense It says "unknown command nonsense and returns exit code 1. For this reason the script below does not work.

#!/bin/bash
adb tcpip 5037
x=100
until adb connect 192.168.0.$x:5037
do
    echo "For x = $x the return code was $?"
    ((x+=1))
    if [ $x -eq 68 ]; then exit; fi
done
scrcpy


Use grep
The next script looks for the word "failed" in the output generated by adb connect... and continues to iterate until the output does not contain the word "failed". Create a file /home/$USER/bin/PhoneCast.sh:
#!/bin/bash
adb tcpip 5037
x=100
until adb connect 192.168.0.$x:5037 | grep -v "failed"
do
    echo "For x = $x the return code was $?" 
    ((x+=1))
    if [ $x -eq 255 ]; then exit; fi
done
scrcpy

Make the file executable using the command:
chmod +x /home/$USER/bin/PhoneCast.sh

Run the script by typing the following:
PhoneCast.sh

If everything is right it should work.
How does it work?
The until looks for the numeric value 0. When the adb connect... runs it always returns 0, but it produces a text output that contains the word "failed" if the command fails to connect. That output is piped into the grep command which check if the word "failed" does not exist (the -v option) in the output of the adb connect....
Now until is checking for the exit command of grep which returns 0 if it does not find the word "failed" in the output of adb connect...
The ((x+=1)) adds 1 to the value of x.
The if line checks x=255 and exits the script. Note, it won't run the last line scrcpy if x reaches 254 and the connection fails.
Hope this helps

Thanks, but does not work and has syntax errors.  afik, the 'for' 'while' 'until' loops apply to numeric values and expressions.  What I need is to test for the connect. I think I will need an If Then Else loop. But I have yet to determine what are the return values for a true or false connect.

Many thanks. The gep version works!  I too, thought about a string condition, but did not how to do. This has been a great little tutorial for bash. But I have one issue remaining... The script works when I enter the commands in terminal. I created an executable .sh file on my desktop. When I use my mouse to execute the .sh file, nothing occurs. Any ideas?  ... gratefully yours...

Thanks for reply. I have named the script, PhoneCast.sh
When I execute the .sh file in terminal, this is the result...
~/Desktop$ ./PhoneCast.sh
restarting in TCP mode port: 5037
For x = 100 the return code was 1
./PhoneCast.sh: 8: x+=1: not found

Excuse my delay; I had a hospital stay.  The script works.  The problems I have now are with the ADB app; specifically to establish a connection.  I am researching this.  Thanks!

Take care of your health and get well soon.

Maybe this will work for you? The adb command always returns true (success) even if it doesnt connect ?for i in {100..200}
do
adb disconnect
adb connect 192.168.0.$i:5037 || { let i=$(expr $i - 1); continue; }
$(adb shell scrcpy)
adb kill-server
done
ps: i couldnt find ``scrcpy'' command?

Why are you decrementing i at each iteration? i is incrementing naturally because of the outer for loop, and assigning i within the loop won't affect the next i being processed regardless. Just adb connect 192.168.0.$i:5037 || continue (by the way this obviously assumes the range of possible IPs being restricted to 192.168.0.100-200)

The script will attempt to connect 200 iterations. If the $i value needed is 102, there must be some way to receive a return code for a successful connect, then exit the script, without running thru 198 more iterations. I see this as an if then else loop. But I cannot yet determine what is the return code for a successful connect. thanks.
